# Prove that free modules are projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

> Prove that free modules are projective.

Help me.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? It is the question about the prove of mathematical theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definition: $M$ is projective iff for every surjective morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$, and every morphism $g:M\rightarrow B$ there is morphism $h:M\rightarrow A$ such that $fh=g$.

Now if $M$ is free with base $\{x_i\}$ then we can define $g$ setting $x_i\mapsto a_i\in f^{-1}(g(x_i))$.

Comment: Why "we can define $g$ setting $x_i\mapsto a_i\in f^{-1}(g(x_i))$" implies $M$ is projective?

Comment: Because $M$ is projective if such map exists and module is free if every function from base can be extended to module morphism.

Comment: $f$ is just a subjection, why should $f^{-1}$ exists. Or in other words why the pre-image of $g(x_i)$ be unique?

Comment: @Babai It does not have to exist $f^{-1}(y)$ is just a symbol for elements that are mapped to $y$ via $f$. And "pre-image" of $g(x_i)$ does not have to be unique. To construct the mapping you just have to peek any element of the pre-image.